# How to change data in a json response

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting a jsonResponse with some data like this:

```
[ 
   { 
      "date":"2019-02-15",
      "value":"5456"
   },
   { 
      "date":"2019-02-15",
      "value":"5456"
   },
   { 
      "date":"2019-02-15",
      "value":"5456"
   },
   { 
      "date":"2019-02-15",
      "value":"-5456"
   }
]
```

What I need is to change the delimiter in the date from " - " to " / ". I need date like: 2019/03/14

I tried to change them like this:

```
json.replace(/-/g, "/");
```

and it works but there is a problem. If for some reason the value data is negative -524. That minus will change also.

There si any way to change the delimiter without affecting another data ?

I need to keep the jsonResponse but with the delimiter change.

Comment: Instead of using json.replace, use string.replace, same arguments

Answer (score 2):

You have to loop through the array using [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and change the `date` :

```js
const response = [
  {
    date: "2019-02-15",
    value: "5456"
  },
  {
    date: "2019-02-15",
    value: "5456"
  },
  {
    date: "2019-02-15",
    value: "5456"
  },
  {
    date: "2019-02-15",
    value: "-5456"
  }
];

const result = response.map(obj => ({ ...obj, date: obj.date.replace(/-/g, "/") }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `Array.prototype.map` to iterate over the objects in the array.
2. Format the `date` property by calling `String.prototype.split("-")` to split the `date` string it into an array using the `-` separator.
3. Then join the array using `/` by calling `Array.prtotype.join("/")`:

```js
const data = [ 
   { 
      "date":"2019-02-15",
      "value":"5456"
   },
   { 
      "date":"2019-02-15",
      "value":"5456"
   },
   { 
      "date":"2019-02-15",
      "value":"5456"
   },
   { 
      "date":"2019-02-15",
      "value":"-5456"
   }
];

//This function does not modify the original object or the array
function formatDate(){
  return data.map(o => ({...o, date: o.date.split("-").join("/")}));
}
console.log(formatDate(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try map

```js
let response = json.map(doc => doc.date.replace(/-/g, "/"))
```